# Difficulties installing Networkx module properly on OSX

Tags: python, macos, installation, networkx

I want to use `networkx` (python 2.7.10).
Therefore I have installed `networkx` with pip. But when I actually tried to import it, I got this error `No module named networkx`

When I check `pip freeze`, it return `networkx==1.11`

Although I tried to reinstall it, it returned

```
Requirement already satisfied: networkx in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=3.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from networkx)
```

I can't figure out what I should do to get it to work.
My Mac version is 10.11.6

It would be greatly appreciated if you could explain the details.

Comment: can you check which python you're using with `which python`?

Comment: post some code (your import statement and a full error readout)?  Agree with @pml; make sure the python 2 is actually what is being used.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My Python is python 2.7.10.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would really not mess with your systems python.

If you are going to be doing data science work.  I would suggest you get a Python distribution like [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) and run it inside your home directory so you don't do something you will probably regret.

It has an easy installer.  The key during the install to make this problem go away is to say "YES" to changing your path.

After that you will have a nice GUI tool for installing packages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to install anaconda.

Comment: How did it go??

Comment: It is much easier than using other way !! Thank you very much.